# Overloaded Double Equal operator is not working as expected

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

its a long doubly linked list code. but the problem is when i overload the operator, i think the function is not getting called. I have tried to put a debugging line printing here, but that does never show up.
so i wanted if two of my Doubly Linked List are equal , it should print true.

```
class Node
{
    friend class Dlist;
private:
    string s;
    string language;
    int noOfNode;
    Node * Next;
    Node * Prev;
};


class Dlist
{
private:
    Node * Header;
    Node * Trailer;
    int n;

public:
    Dlist();//default constructor
    void AddFront(string e,string lang);
    void Print();
    void AddBack(string e,string lang);
    void RemoveFront();
    void RemoveBack();
    int Empty(){ if (Header->Next==Trailer) return 1 ; else return 0;}
    int CountLanguage(string lang);
    int search (string r);
    void RemoveWord(string tempW);
    void changeIndex(Node* node,int newIndex);
    void sortDLL();
    void PrintRev();
    void AddInOrder(string s, string language);
    bool operator==(const Dlist &Q);
};
bool Dlist::operator ==(const Dlist &Q)
{
    Node*tempL1=Header->Next;
    Node *tempL2=Q.Header->Next;
    int count=0;
    cout<<"here"<<endl;
    if(n==Q.n)
    {
        while(tempL1!=Trailer && tempL2!=Q.Trailer)
        {
            if(tempL1->s==tempL2->s && tempL1->language==tempL2->language
                ){
                tempL1=tempL1->Next;
                tempL2=tempL2->Next;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;

}
int main()
{
    Dlist *x = new Dlist;
    Dlist *y = new Dlist;
    Dlist *z = new Dlist;

    inputX();
    inputY();
    cout<<endl<<"test if the first list and the second are equal?? :"<<endl;
    cout<<(x==y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at your `operator ==`.  What is the type of the parameter?  Does it match the type of `x` and `y`?

Comment: should it be bool operator==(const Dlist *Q);?

Comment: That may work, but wouldn't it be better to compare the objects pointed at by `x` and `y` instead?

Comment: @cigien what do you mean by comparing the objects? actually im checking every node by iterating through the list

Comment: @AntarRoy You can't overload operators for pointers.  Instead make `x`, `y`, and `z` non-pointers

Comment: I was referring to Vlad's solution below, but you can also use Nathan's approach. Either way, don't change your comparison function to compare pointers. That's not the right thing to do, even if it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the operator should be declared with the qualifier const

```
bool operator==(const Dlist &Q) const;
```

In this statement

```
cout<<(x==y)<<endl;
```

the used expression is a comparison of two pointers `x` and `y` declared like

```
Dlist *x = new Dlist;
Dlist *y = new Dlist;
```

You need to compare the pointed objects like

```
cout<<( *x == *y )<<endl;
```

Pay attention to that there is a logical error in this code snippet

```
    while(tempL1!=Trailer && tempL2!=Q.Trailer)
    {
        if(tempL1->s==tempL2->s && tempL1->language==tempL2->language
            ){
            tempL1=tempL1->Next;
            tempL2=tempL2->Next;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Instead of the statement

```
    return true;
```

you should write

```
    return tempL1 == Trailer && tempL2 == Q.Trailer;
```

Comment: Actually Trailer is a dummy node. so it doesnt matter if its equal or not. btw thanks